# "временно неразъяснённое" или "временно не разъяснённое"

Tags: орфография, причастия

В [Практикуме по литературе за 9 класс](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ddMHAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&source=bl&ots=IVHu59Cb4N&sig=ZzwXA3C_u4nXgaKB3-RjdRuHGFU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ew-3VIu6LsK9Ua6TgtgD&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&f=false) читаем:

> ..., одно недоразумение, временно **не** *разъяснённое*.

У [Беннедикта Сарнова](https://books.google.ru/books?id=xY-6AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT190&lpg=PT190&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&source=bl&ots=aaY2wljq_j&sig=vIOzBJvY9M7onz3izTvA0pTNRd8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ew-3VIu6LsK9Ua6TgtgD&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%22&f=false) читаем:

> ..., одно недоразумение, временно *неразъяснённое*.

Так как писать частицу **не**: слитно или раздельно? Есть две возможные причины писать раздельно: приставка *раз* и зависимое слово *временно*. Но является ли наречие *временно* достаточным условием для отделения частицы от причастия? А насчёт присавки, так нет глагола *яснить* (но есть *разъяснить*); к тому же есть прилагательное *необъяснённый* (приставка *об*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависимые слова, которые влияют на написание НЕ с причастиями, эти причастия "наследуют" из глагольных сочетаний: еще не написал книгу - еще не написанная книга.

Можно сказать: временно не разъяснить недоразумение? Скорее всего, нет, поэтому "временно" относится к уже образованному причастию: разъясненное - неразъясненное (неясное, смутное)- временно (пока еще) неясное, неразъясненное.

И вот результат: если применяем формальное правило, то пишем раздельно (что характерно для школьной практики). В то же время автор имеет право на слитное написание НЕ в силу указанных причин и более тонкого (художественного, авторского) понимания русской речи.

Answer (score 4):

Здесь оба варианта допустимы. Хотите отрицать разъясненность – пишите раздельно, утверждать неразъясненность – слитно.

Comment: Уважаемый Niemand, как  произносится  ваш  ник  по-русски ?  Вопрос  не  по  делу,  но  интересно.

Comment: Да уж, не по делу... ))) По-русски он произносится примерно как [нимант].